# Google Maps Will Not Load In My PhoneGap Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova

Is it possible to use Google Maps API V3 for mobile app development when using PhoneGap/Cordova? My index page has a link to a map page that has the following in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <title>Map Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#map-canvas').gmap({'center': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'zoom': 10, 'disableDefaultUI':false, 'callback': function() {}});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm including the Google Maps jQuery plugin and the other necessary files. When I test the app in my desktop browser, Ripple, and (mysteriously) on my old Samsung Galaxy S the map loads up just fine. When I try it in the Android emulator or on an Galaxy S4 the map does not load and I am left with an empty white page. Is there a different/better way I could be using Google Maps on and Android app or is there something I need to change in my above code? Thanks.

Comment: Are you remembering to whitelist the `<access origin="http://google.com" />` domain?

Comment: Thank you! You and Brian got me back on track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script tag to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" />
```

I believe the one you are using is for v2 as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178549/738262)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the google apis couldn't be loaded because the app didn't had permission to access the internet. 
So dont' forget to add internet access permission to your app in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And for other features (location, camera,...) make sure the corresponding permission has been set for this app and device

Comment: remember to do this after a plugin uninstall as sometimes the permission is removed