# PhoneGap, Embedded Google map is not showing in Android Build

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, phonegap-build

I have created phonegap project and added one html tag:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Sydnew%20Opera%20House&key=MY_KEY" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I launch PhoneGap Desktop, embedded Google Map shows successfully in my browser. However, when I build it for Android, Map does not shows.

In my `config.xml` I have added these lines of tags:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

It already have permissions for Internet. Why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

I have added this line of code in my `config.xml`:

```
<allow-navigation href="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/*" />
```

Still it does not showing.

Comment: Have you got any error message in the console? You may want to see if solutions given in these SO posts
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042446/google-maps-doesnt-show-up-in-phonegap-build and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025342/google-maps-will-not-load-in-my-phonegap-android-app) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

All `access` like tags started to work when I have added this plugin to my `confix.xml` file:

```
<plugin name="com.indigoway.cordova.whitelist.whitelistplugin" source="pgb" />
```

Then I have uploaded my project to PhoneGap Build website and downloaded application worked.